# Adding root certificate with CF 3.5

Tags: c#, compact-framework, x509certificate

I have a problem with adding the my certificate file to the windows mobile x509 storage.
I use the following test program:

```
byte[] certifictateData = FileToByteArray(appPath + "cert.cer");
X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate(certifictateData);

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
int i = store.Certificates.Add(certificate);
store.Close();
```

On the device are 28 root certs installed. after adding my I receive 29 as value.
but when I try to open store.Certificates[28] there is an OutOfRangeException
Even after closing there is no entry in the certificate storage.

When I open the cert.cer file in the mobile browser it's added without any message.

What can I do?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I also experienced with this namespace.
Never the less you do a great job with the Small Device Framework..
this is my quick and cheaper solution ;)

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(appPath + "cert.cer", "");
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(psi);
```

The only drawback is that a message pops up and shows the import result.

Comment: FWIW, for root certificates, even if you call the API directly like I did, you still get that popup.  Adding it to the "My" store, however, is completely silent.

Comment: My WindowsCE devices do not seem to have a file association for .cer so the OS cannot execute it. Any idea what i need to add to the registry so associate this with something.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that the X509Store (really the entire namespace) in the Compact Framework [is completely useless](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2011/11/22/X509CertificatesCompactFrameworkWTF.aspx).  I ended up implementing the entire set of APIs for importing both certificates and private keys.  I put that work into [the latest SDF](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx), though IIRC someone found a bug in that code since, which I fixed internally, but I don't recall if that fix has propagated publicly.